# Unique selection of a tag in Selenium for a button without text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For dynamic buttons (one each in every row of a dynamic table) with no text and following implementation, how to identify the button 2 in a unique manner?

**Button 1 (Hidden):**

```
<button class="btn btn-clear" data-bind="click: $parent.editDilution, visible: expanded" style="display: none;">
    <i class="icon-checkmark dark-blue"></i>
</button>
```

**Button 2 (Visible):**

```
<button class="btn btn-clear" data-bind="click: $parent.editDilution, visible: expanded">
    <i class="icon-checkmark dark-blue"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: If it was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following xpath.

```
//table//tr/td[1]//button[@class='btn btn-clear' and not(@style)]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, it will be an entry of each row in a table. It will be a dynamic in nature.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

This might help to identify button 2:

```
.//button[not(@style)]
```

This will select all `buttons` without `style` attribute since visible buttons will not have this attribute.